# Css not applied on angular-bootstrap-select component

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-select

I am trying to use the angular-bootstrap-select component. I have installed via bower jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-select and angular.

All theses frameworks are loaded (including css). However, when I type:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

The bootstrap-select style is not applied on the element. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check the your script source file path and make sure it's correct.
e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..bower_components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js"></script>
```

make sure the right file path is used.

Comment: Hmmm, did you link the select2 css file too? 

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/select2.css">`
If you did, make sure "jquery must be loaded before angular so that it doesn't use jqLite internally" as stated on select2 github page; https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Comment: By digging, it work ouside an ng-include but not inside an ng-include. I am not sure of what to do. JQuery is loaded before angular.